# How to change github default name for pull request

Tags: templates, github

I now how to create [pull request templates with github](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository/) but I can't find if there is a way to change the default name added by GitHub when opening a PR, ie the name of the last commit.

-- EDIT --

I have found that using `hub` for creating PR with command line:

```
hub pull-request -F template_file.md
```

the first line of the template file provided is used as a title by GitHub. However this behaviour is not the one encountered when creating the PR through github.com

Comment: Do you mean, how can you edit it after you've created it? Or do you want to set up some kind of rule for what it should default to?

Comment: I know I can edit by hand but I'd like to change the default behaviour yes.